# XGBoost error: "XGBoost version not compiled with GPU support."

Tags: python, xgboost

I am training and analyzing xgboost classification algorithm and receiving the following error when I execute the following lines. Can someone please let me know what is wrong. I tried upgrading xgboost to v1.4.2. It did not help.

```
    eval_set = [(X_test_subsample, y_test_subsample)]   
    y_pred = clf.fit(X_train_subsample, y_train_subsample,eval_set=eval_set,  eval_metric=["mlogloss", "merror"],  early_stopping_rounds=10).predict(X_test_subsample)
```

error:

```
XGBoostError
Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [53], line 1
----> 1 y_pred = clf.fit(X_train_subsample, y_train_subsample,eval_set=eval_set,  eval_metric=["mlogloss", "merror"],  early_stopping_rounds=10).predict(X_test_subsample)

    File /conda_envs/my_env_one/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/core.py:436, in _deprecate_positional_args.<locals>.inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
        434 for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args):
        435     kwargs[k] = arg
    --> 436 return f(**kwargs)
    
    File /conda_envs/my_env_one/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py:1176, in XGBClassifier.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, base_margin, eval_set, eval_metric, early_stopping_rounds, verbose, xgb_model, sample_weight_eval_set, base_margin_eval_set, feature_weights, callbacks)
       1156     raise ValueError("Please reshape the input data X into 2-dimensional matrix.")
       1158 train_dmatrix, evals = _wrap_evaluation_matrices(
       1159     missing=self.missing,
       1160     X=X,
       (...)
       1173     label_transform=label_transform,
       1174 )
    -> 1176 self._Booster = train(
       1177     params,
       1178     train_dmatrix,
       1179     self.get_num_boosting_rounds(),
       1180     evals=evals,
       1181     early_stopping_rounds=early_stopping_rounds,
       1182     evals_result=evals_result,
       1183     obj=obj,
       1184     feval=feval,
       1185     verbose_eval=verbose,
       1186     xgb_model=model,
       1187     callbacks=callbacks,
       1188 )
       1190 if not callable(self.objective):
       1191     self.objective = params["objective"]
    
    File /conda_envs/my_env_one/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/training.py:189, in train(params, dtrain, num_boost_round, evals, obj, feval, maximize, early_stopping_rounds, evals_result, verbose_eval, xgb_model, callbacks)
        113 def train(params, dtrain, num_boost_round=10, evals=(), obj=None, feval=None,
        114           maximize=None, early_stopping_rounds=None, evals_result=None,
        115           verbose_eval=True, xgb_model=None, callbacks=None):
        116     # pylint: disable=too-many-statements,too-many-branches, attribute-defined-outside-init
        117     """Train a booster with given parameters.
        118 
        119     Parameters
       (...)
        187     Booster : a trained booster model
        188     """
    --> 189     bst = _train_internal(params, dtrain,
        190                           num_boost_round=num_boost_round,
        191                           evals=evals,
        192                           obj=obj, feval=feval,
        193                           xgb_model=xgb_model, callbacks=callbacks,
        194                           verbose_eval=verbose_eval,
        195                           evals_result=evals_result,
        196                           maximize=maximize,
        197                           early_stopping_rounds=early_stopping_rounds)
        198     return bst
    
    File /conda_envs/my_env_one/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/training.py:76, in _train_internal(params, dtrain, num_boost_round, evals, obj, feval, xgb_model, callbacks, evals_result, maximize, verbose_eval, early_stopping_rounds)
         70 else:
         71     callbacks = _configure_deprecated_callbacks(
         72         verbose_eval, early_stopping_rounds, maximize, start_iteration,
         73         num_boost_round, feval, evals_result, callbacks,
         74         show_stdv=False, cvfolds=None)
    ---> 76 bst = callbacks.before_training(bst)
         78 for i in range(start_iteration, num_boost_round):
         79     if callbacks.before_iteration(bst, i, dtrain, evals):
    
    File /conda_envs/my_env_one/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/callback.py:376, in CallbackContainer.before_training(self, model)
        374 '''Function called before training.'''
        375 for c in self.callbacks:
    --> 376     model = c.before_training(model=model)
        377     msg = 'before_training should return the model'
        378     if self.is_cv:
    
    File /conda_envs/my_env_one/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/callback.py:515, in EarlyStopping.before_training(self, model)
        514 def before_training(self, model):
    --> 515     self.starting_round = model.num_boosted_rounds()
        516     return model
    
    File /conda_envs/my_env_one/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/core.py:2007, in Booster.num_boosted_rounds(self)
       2005 rounds = ctypes.c_int()
       2006 assert self.handle is not None
    -> 2007 _check_call(_LIB.XGBoosterBoostedRounds(self.handle, ctypes.byref(rounds)))
       2008 return rounds.value
    
    File /conda_envs/my_env_one/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/core.py:210, in _check_call(ret)
        199 """Check the return value of C API call
        200 
        201 This function will raise exception when error occurs.
       (...)
        207     return value from API calls
        208 """
        209 if ret != 0:
    --> 210     raise XGBoostError(py_str(_LIB.XGBGetLastError()))
    
    XGBoostError: [10:03:05] /home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/xgboost-split_1631904754241/work/src/gbm/../common/common.h:157: XGBoost version not compiled with GPU support.
    Stack trace:
      [bt] (0) /conda_envs/my_env_one/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x196a2b) [0x2afae7167a2b]
      [bt] (1) conda_envs/my_env_one/lib/libxgboost.so(xgboost::gbm::GBTree::ConfigureUpdaters()+0xd8) [0x2afae7167c48]
      [bt] (2) conda_envs/my_env_one/lib/libxgboost.so(xgboost::gbm::GBTree::Configure(std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > const&)+0x309) [0x2afae717b6f9]
```